# Saving image from a URL asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

So i have already gone through almost all questions on SO, and I have put them all together to create a method that accepts two paramaters, first is the `URL` of the image to download and display in `UIImageView` and second is the placeholder image for that `UIImageView`. I want to save the image so that it won't be downloaded every time. I have used SDWebImage to download the image, however i had some confusion when it came to saving the image in documents directory using SDWebImage, so i decided not to use it. I used `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()` and my method now looks like :

```
- (void)saveImageFromURL:(UIImage*)image:(NSURL*)imageURL {

NSString *url = [imageURL absoluteString];
NSArray *parts = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", filename]];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath];

if (fileExists) {
    NSLog(@"File already exists");
    _myUIImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fullPath];
    return;
}

else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.myUIImage sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:image];
        UIImage *imageFromURL = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
        NSData *imageDataNew = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageFromURL);
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageDataNew attributes:nil];
    });
  }
}
```

I have a couple of questions, is this implementation good enough since i am working on a app that will be on app store ? Will the downloading of the image from URL be done asynchronously ? (i know i am using `dispatch_async` but just need to confirm). If yes, then this wont block my UI, right ?

Comment: hardly. since you're doing this in dispatch_get_main_queue

Comment: Did you mean to type: ```dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()``` without the final bracket, or is that a typo?

Comment: dispatch_sync - as you can expect from it name - it will be Synchronous. That mean if you call saveImageFromURL from main thread - it will be blocked.  MoreOver dispatch_get_main_queue()  - is actually a main Thread.
So your implementation will block UI anyway.

Comment: Sorry all, it's dispatch_async.

Comment: @DoN1cK - Looks good now ?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter - That was a typo, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) - Now it will be called a little bit later, But still in main thread and will block UI. 
dispatch_get_main_queue() = Main Thread. You can try to use dispatch_get_global_queue
You should read few tutorials and check docs about GCD.

Comment: @DoN1cK- Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

// *** Load Image from URL Asynchronously without blocking Main thread ***    
UIImage *imageFromURL = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        // *** Create file path to DocumentDirectory ***
        NSString * docDirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
        NSString *filePath = [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.jpg"]

        // *** Write Image to disk *** 
        BOOL isSaved = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f) writeToFile:dirPath atomically:YES];
        if(isSaved)
        {
            NSLog(@"Image write to disc successfully.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of this can i not have just the saving of image asynchronously like i have done, what is the difference between the two. Sorry i am new to iOS development.

Comment: You can do it, but when you have a situation that download image , save & display in `UIImageView` at that time you will need to update it in  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)` only, otherwise it will not reflect on screen. All the UI operation must be performed on Main Thread only.

Comment: Sorry but i don't get what you are trying to convey, you mean to say if the image is not in my dir then my code won't work ?

Comment: [self.myUIImage sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:image]; downloads and displays image asynchronously and until the image is downloaded it displays the placeholder image. Sounds good ?

Comment: You can use anything whichever suits best in your requirement.